# React Native slow in cycle for of 1000 elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to do a "for" cycle of 1000 elements more or less, the problem is that takes a lot.
I already tried to use flatList, but nothing change

Here is my code:

```
componentWillMount(){
  for(var i = 0; i<xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title").length; i++){
    try {
      arrayElementi[i] = (
          <View key={"elemento"+i}>
          <Text style={[styles.categoria, {backgroundColor: colori[xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("appcategoryparent")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue]}]}>{xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("appcategoryparent")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue}</Text>
      <Text>{xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[i+2].childNodes[0].nodeValue}</Text>
      <Text>{xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue}</Text>
      </View>
    );
      this.setState({
        data: arrayElementi
      })
    } catch (e) {

    } finally {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: give it a try it in render block ;)

Comment: Is the same :( .

Comment: You should have better performance without try/catch, do you really need it ? Can you share your FlatList implementation too ?

Comment: No, also if write
for (var i = 0, i<1000; i++){
  console.log(i);
}
Takes a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You should use setState method out of the for loop. Because in each loop you can call setState and force to render page.

Comment: Yes, but also if I write
for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++){
console.log(i)
}
takes a lot